# ThreadStart reference error

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I've got a problem after following some basic code for creating a thread.

I have a method that I'm using for a callback on the threadstart but I'm getting an error,

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Program.ServerUDP'

on this, (ServerUDP).

```
public void Server.UDP(){}
static void Main(string[] args) { 
     Thread UDPThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ServerUDP)); 
}
```

Both are contained within the same class, **Program**.

Am I missing something obvious here? All the code I've looked up basically runs like this and I've even tried to move the declaration of the Thread out of the main and as a property of the class but it's the same issue.

Comment: You can only access static methods inside static method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServerUDP should be made as static method

Comment: This worked, it's strange that no example or tutorial states it's a static that is needed, I'm even working from tutorials from a book.

Comment: Well if you think about it, it's pretty straight forward. A static method doesn't know anything about an object instance. As it doesn't reference to any.

Comment: I tried using this.ServerUDP but it didn't work. 

I don't know what happens when the program runs but I expected that the class with main inside would automatically create an instance, is this not the case?

Answer (score 0):

You can only access that method if you specify/use an instance of the `Server` class. So if it doesn't use anything `object` specific, you can just make the method static. It's pretty weird that you have `Server.UDP` specified, that indicates in just using `new Server().UDP();`

Anyway you also have to write it like this when you've fixed it:

```
new ThreadStart(() => ServerUDP());
```